# How to obtain unique results from a SELECT with JOINed records?

Tags: sql, hibernate

I have these 2 tables which I would like to query for a single unique record:

```
create table active_pairs
(
    id                    integer,
    pair                  text,
    exchange_id           integer
);


create table exchanges
(                        
    exchange_id         integer,
    exchange_full_name  text
);

INSERT INTO active_pairs (pair, exchange_id)

VALUES ('London/Berlin', 2),
       ('London/Berlin', 3),
       ('Paris/Berlin', 4),
       ('Paris/Berlin', 3),
       ('Oslo/Berlin', 2),
       ('Oslo/Berlin', 6),
       ('Huston/Berlin', 2);
       
INSERT INTO exchanges (exchange_id, exchange_full_name)

VALUES (2, 'Exchange 1'),
       (3, 'Exchange 2'),
       (4, 'Exchange 3'),
       (3, 'Exchange 21'),
       (2, 'Exchange 12'),
       (6, 'Exchange 11'),
       (2, 'Exchange 31');
```

Query to list items with only one `pair` record:

```
SELECT *  FROM active_pairs ap
    INNER JOIN exchanges ce on ap.exchange_id = ce.exchange_id
WHERE ap.exchange_id = :exchangeId
GROUP BY pair, ap.exchange_id, ce.exchange_id, ap.id
HAVING COUNT(ap.pair) = 1
ORDER BY :sort
LIMIT :limit
OFFSET :offset
```

When I run the query I don't get proper result. I Need to get only `Huston/Berlin` because this is unique record(NOTE we have another record with `exchange_id = 2`). Now I get into result `Huston/Berlin` and 'London/Berlin' with `exchange_id = 2` which is not correct.

Another example: When I make query for exchange_id=4 I need to get empty result because as you can see I have `Paris/Berlin` for exchange_id `3` and `4`.

Can you advice how I can fix this issue?

Comment: You can't reference tables not found in the `FROM` clause. I.e. only `cp` columns are allowed.

Comment: Your design is still weird, which you've been told before. active_pairs should have separate columns for each part of the pairs. E.g. London in one column, and Berlin in the other.

Comment: This is the design which hI received and I cannot change it.

Comment: What's the expected result, when having the specified sample data?

Comment: The expected results logic is a bit confusing. So the only row expected to be returned is 'Huston/Berlin', because it's the only unique row?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Please share some desired output in table format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## SQL

```
SELECT ap.*, ce.* FROM active_pairs ap
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT pair
   FROM active_pairs
   GROUP BY pair
   HAVING COUNT(*) = 1) subq
  ON ap.pair = subq.pair
INNER JOIN exchanges ce
  ON ap.exchange_id = ce.exchange_id
WHERE ap.exchange_id = :exchangeId
ORDER BY :sort
LIMIT :limit
OFFSET :offset;
```

## Explanation

The subquery (`subq`) filters to only include pair names that appear once. This is then joined back to the `active_pairs` table to get the `exchange_id` and then joined to the exchanges table as per your original query.

## Demo

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b3e2dcc5d09401e5bed1f42fdde82a6b

Comment: I need also all the available table rows. I tried to replace `SELECT *
   FROM common.active_pairs ap2` but I get ` ERROR: column "ap2........." must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function` Any idea how to implement this?

Comment: Can you advise, please?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question - what is `common`? Please post the full SQL you are trying.

Comment: Common is the DB scheme.

Comment: Please post full SQL you are trying

Comment: The issue is fixed. Your SQL query is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Without any more samples to check the results, the solution can be something like this:

```
SELECT ap.pair, ap.exchange_id, ce.exchange_id, ap.id  FROM active_pairs ap
    INNER JOIN exchanges ce on ap.exchange_id = ce.exchange_id
    INNER JOIN (SELECT pair FROM active_pairs GROUP BY pair HAVING COUNT(pair) = 1) p on p.pair = ap.pair
WHERE ap.exchange_id = :exchangeId
GROUP BY pair, ap.exchange_id, ce.exchange_id, ap.id
ORDER BY :sort
LIMIT :limit
OFFSET :offset
```

I guess you only want unique active pair names from the small example you gave.

Comment: Thanks, I just updated the description because it was not well explained enough.

Answer (score 0):

IF I understand correctly , here is what you want to do :

```
select * from (
   select *, count(*) over (partition by pair) as cc from active_pairs 
   ) t join exchanges e on t.exchange_id = e.exchange_id and t.cc=1
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=49a637124b28ba08e7485b13a824dfaf)*