# Join table rows with empty key

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have these 2 tables which I would like to query:

```
create table active_pairs
(
    pair                  text,
    exchange_id           integer
);


create table exchanges
(                        
    exchange_id         integer,
    exchange_full_name  text
);

INSERT INTO active_pairs (pair, exchange_id)

VALUES ('London/Berlin', 2),
       ('London/Berlin', 3),
       ('Paris/Berlin', 4),
       ('Paris/Berlin', 3),
       ('Oslo/Berlin', 2),
       ('Oslo/Berlin', 6),
       ('Huston/Berlin', 2);
       
INSERT INTO exchanges (exchange_id)

VALUES (2, 'Exchange 1'),
       (3, 'Exchange 2'),
       (4, 'Exchange 3'),
       (3, 'Exchange 21'),
       (2, 'Exchange 12'),
       (6, 'Exchange 11'),
       (2, 'Exchange 31');
```

I use these queries to list all pairs:

Query to list items:

```
SELECT * FROM common.active_pairs ap
    INNER JOIN common.exchanges ce on ap.exchange_id = ce.exchange_id
WHERE ap.exchange_id = 1
GROUP BY pair, ap.exchange_id, ce.exchange_id, ap.id
HAVING COUNT(ap.pair) = 1;
```

I get as a result 172 rows.

Query to count rows to calculate pagination:

```
SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(*) OVER () counter
FROM common.active_pairs cp
    INNER JOIN common.exchanges ce on cp.exchange_id = ce.exchange_id
WHERE cp.exchange_id = 1
GROUP BY pair
HAVING COUNT(cp.pair) = 1
```

I get as a result 158 rows.

I should be able to get equal total numbers from both queries in order to calculate properly pagination.

Is it possible that records with empty `exchange_id` in giving the different result?

Comment: `INSERT INTO exchanges (exchange_id, exchange_full_name)`

Comment: If you use different GROUP BY specifications, you'll end up with different groups, which might affect the number of cp.pair values

Comment: ap.id does not exist

Comment: Please include the expected result in the question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to obtain unique results from a SELECT with JOINed records?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71209065/how-to-obtain-unique-results-from-a-select-with-joined-records)

Answer (score 0):

You do not group by `active_pairs.exchange_id` but only by the name of the pair (`active_pairs.pair`). If that name is not unique, pairs with the same name but different ID are counted as one in your pagination query.