# Count rows from SQL query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have these 2 tables which I would like to query:

```
create table active_pairs
(
    pair                  text,
    exchange_id           integer
);


create table exchanges
(                        
    exchange_id         integer,
    exchange_full_name  text
);

INSERT INTO active_pairs (pair, exchange_id)

VALUES ('London/Berlin', 2),
       ('London/Berlin', 3),
       ('Paris/Berlin', 4),
       ('Paris/Berlin', 3),
       ('Oslo/Berlin', 2),
       ('Oslo/Berlin', 6),
       ('Huston/Berlin', 2);
       
INSERT INTO exchanges (exchange_id, exchange_full_name)

VALUES (2, 'Exchange 1'),
       (3, 'Exchange 2'),
       (4, 'Exchange 3'),
       (3, 'Exchange 21'),
       (2, 'Exchange 12'),
       (6, 'Exchange 11'),
       (2, 'Exchange 31');
```

I use these queries to list all pairs:

Query to list items:

```
WITH pairs AS(SELECT *
FROM common.active_pairs cp
GROUP BY pair, cp.exchange_id, exchange_id, cp.id, cp.min_order_exchange_id, cp.exchange_active, cp.prime_active, cp.otc_active, cp.marketmaking_active, cp.arbitrage_active
HAVING COUNT(pair) = 1)
SELECT p.pair, p.exchange_id, e.exchange_long_name
FROM pairs p
INNER JOIN common.exchanges e ON(p.exchange_id = e.exchange_id);
```

Query to count rows to calculate pagination:

```
WITH pairs AS(SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(*) OVER () counter
FROM common.active_pairs cp
GROUP BY pair, cp.exchange_id, exchange_id
HAVING COUNT(pair) = 1)
SELECT e.exchange_id
FROM pairs p
INNER JOIN common.exchanges e ON(p.exchange_id = e.exchange_id);
```

I get error `[42703] ERROR: column p.exchange_id does not exist` for `p.exchange_id`.

I also tried this:

```
select ap.pair
     , COUNT(1) total_exchange_id
     , COUNT(DISTINCT ap.exchange_id) total_distinct_exchange_id
from active_pairs ap
inner join exchanges e
        on ap.exchange_id = e.exchange_id 
       -- and ap.exchange_id = 2 
group by ap.pair
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=c7c945ad52da59d307ed7f1c29da9582

But I can't get count of the rows.

Is there some way to edit the query to count the rows using JOIN?

Comment: Sample data is great, but you also should _specify_ the expected result.

Comment: I need just a number `122` for example - the total number of rows.

Comment: Posting [the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71239339/count-rows-using-sql-query-with-join) twice is not a good idea. Please close one of the questions.

Comment: `select count(*) from (<your query>)`