# Return filtered result form JOIN and DISTINCT query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have these 2 tables which I would like to query for a single unique record:

```
create table active_pairs
(
    id                    integer,
    pair                  text,
    exchange_id           integer
);


create table exchanges
(                        
    exchange_id         integer,
    exchange_full_name  text
);

INSERT INTO active_pairs (pair, exchange_id)

VALUES ('London/Berlin', 2),
       ('London/Berlin', 3),
       ('Paris/Berlin', 4),
       ('Paris/Berlin', 3),
       ('Oslo/Berlin', 2),
       ('Oslo/Berlin', 6),
       ('Huston/Berlin', 2);
       
INSERT INTO exchanges (exchange_id, exchange_full_name)

VALUES (2, 'Exchange 1'),
       (3, 'Exchange 2'),
       (4, 'Exchange 3'),
       (3, 'Exchange 21'),
       (2, 'Exchange 12'),
       (6, 'Exchange 11'),
       (2, 'Exchange 31');
```

Query to list items with only one `pair` record:

```
SELECT *  FROM active_pairs ap
    INNER JOIN exchanges ce on ap.exchange_id = ce.exchange_id
WHERE ap.exchange_id = 2
GROUP BY pair, ap.exchange_id, ce.exchange_id, ap.id
HAVING COUNT(ap.pair) = 1
ORDER BY ap.pair
```

I also tried this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (ap.pair) ap.pair
FROM common.active_pairs ap
    INNER JOIN common.exchanges ce on ap.exchange_id = ce.exchange_id
WHERE ce.exchange_id = 2
```

When I run the query I don't get proper result. I Need to get only `Huston/Berlin` because this is unique record(NOTE we have another record with `exchange_id = 2`). Now I get into result `Huston/Berlin` and 'London/Berlin' with `exchange_id = 2` which is not correct.

Another example: When I make query for exchange_id=4 I need to get empty result because as you can see I have `Paris/Berlin` for exchange_id `3` and `4`.

Additional case to consider: When `exchange_id` table row is empty I should not get the row with empty `exchange_id`.

Can you advice how I can fix this issue?

Comment: Didn't you ask this question yesterday too?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Select is not return unique result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71209065/select-is-not-return-unique-result)

Comment: Stop plastering stackoverflow with almost the same question again and again. Don't you notice that your requests were too vague, so you didn't get the answer you are looking for? When you started your series of requests you were asked to show the expected result. So instead of posting a minimally changed request every some minutes, work on the task yourself. And do this thoroughly, not only two minutes and then post the next request. You are wasting people's time here. The task itself seems easy enough, but I must admit, I'm kinda fed up with this request bombardment and won't write an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you need the info from common.exchanges, but you can do the following:

```
SELECT pair
  FROM active_pairs ap
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM active_pairs other_pairing
                    WHERE other_pairing.pair = ap.pair
                      AND other_pairing.exchange_id != ap.exchange_id)
   AND ap.exchange_id = 2
   AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM exchanges ep WHERE ep.exchange_id = ap.exchange_id)
```

So basically you're looking for any records in active_pairs that don't have any other record in that table with a different exchange_id.

[Working demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=c91a09a4f5c8c5de4c04625108455f7b)

Comment: One additional question: Can you include column `exchange_full_name` into query result, please?

Comment: Well not really because there are multiple of them, right? I don't know what your requirements, but this should be easy to figure out. You can make this a CTE and then join to exchanges, or maybe you need to aggregate them into a single row, no idea. Give it a try.

Comment: SQL code works but I see one issue: When `exchange_id` table row it's empty I get the pair with the empty `exchange_id`. How I can prevent this?

Comment: add an exist clause `... AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM exchanges ep WHERE ep.exchange_id = ap.exchange_id)` - since you're not joining, it will not duplicate the row, you're only checking if any rows exist.

Comment: Can you update the SQL query please?

Comment: Kind remind to update the post.

Comment: Can you really not work it out yourself? Updating the question over and over because you figure out you have to do something new without actually learning a single thing about SQL is not going to lead you anywhere. If you want, feel free to hire a consultant to do the work for you.

Comment: There, I updated it, hopefully you can learn where to put additional predicates in your queries.

Comment: I tested the query but again I get a result with `null` value for `exchange_id`. Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: Can you advise, please?

Answer (score 1):

To select only exchanges that have one and only one pair you need to count pair occurance and filter on that count. So you seemed to be pretty near the solution, so here's your modified statement:

```
SELECT ce.exchange_id, count(ap.id) as pair_counter
FROM common.active_pairs ap
INNER JOIN common.exchanges ce on ap.exchange_id = ce.exchange_id
GROUP BY ce.exchange_id
HAVING count(ap.id)=1
```

You even don't really need the join and would be much faster using the FK only:

```
SELECT ap.id, ap.exchange_id, count(ap.id) as pair_counter
FROM common.active_pairs ap
GROUP BY ap.id, ap.exchange_id
HAVING count(ap.id)=1
```